# What does "go on" mean in: “I know you go on”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs, lyrics

> *[My Heart Will Go On](https://genius.com/Celine-dion-my-heart-will-go-on-love-theme-from-titanic-lyrics)*
>
> Every night in my dreams
> I see you, I feel you
> That is how I know you **go on**
>
> Far across the distance
> And spaces between us
> You have come to show you **go on**
>
> Near, far, wherever you are
> I believe that the heart does go on
> […]

There's something I never understood from the Titanic theme song. We use "go on" in the area I bolded out, and it seems like it's used to mean "You go on without me". The subject is meaning in these two instances, so I am not sure why and why there's no comma. Can someone explain me what is meant exactly?

In the other instances we see the subject, which is often "heart", so it's easy to understand.

It's sung: "That is how I know you, go on"
and "You have come to show you, go on"

Also the tense is confusing.

If she said "That is how I know you went on" it would have made more sense to me and "You have come to show you went on". Is it the right tense? I think it's the right tense, but I rarely see this phrasing and I would like to know what tense is used and why.

Comment: Poetry and art do not need to obey the constraints of what constitutes "proper grammar/art", this, I believe, is true in every language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of "go on" here is "continue", specifically in the context of Jack and Rose, "continue to live".

This usage is not natural at all to use "go on" to mean "be alive", but there are no rules in song lyrics.

In normal life, if someone says, "*That is how I know you go on*", meaning "That is how I know you're still alive", it's a mistake. No native speaker would ever say that.

Comment: Ah, so it's a grammar mistake? I always thought it sounded off and weird.

Comment: @Sayaman Kinda. I'd say it's an intentional violation of the rules of the language for poetic ends. Celine Dion isn't a native speaker, but knows English well enough to do this on purpose.

Comment: Ok, weird, but it's Will Jennings who actually wrote, so I was confused. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_Jennings

Comment: @Sayaman Learn something new every day. He *definitely* knew what he was doing

Comment: Is it ungrammatical, or is it just a unusual figurative use of "go on" that's valid grammatically and "rhetorically", but sound weird?

Comment: @Sayaman The grammar is fine. Semantically, it is incorrect because "go on" never means "be alive". The phrase, "My heart will go on" makes sense because "My heart will **continue beating**" is perfectly natural.

Comment: Ok, but isn't "go on" a metaphorical usage of "go on" to mean continue on living? I thought it was valid semantically, since it's used as a metaphor.

Comment: @Sayaman The phrasal verb "go on" never means "be alive". This song may be the only place in all of English where it does. It's beyond the scope of this site to discuss what can be a metaphor for what. Maybe try Literature.SE or Writing.SE?

Comment: Celine Dion sang the the theme, she didn't write the lyrics as you suggested in the comments "but knows English well enough to do this on purpose." The lyricist was Will Jennings, an American. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_Jennings